# Submit form to certain database based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form with a drop down list...

-optionA

-optionB

-optionC

-optionD

...each option in the list has it's own table in a database.

-optionA_table

-optionB_table

-optionC_table

-optionD_table

Based on the choice a user selects from the drop-down list, when they submit the form I'd like for corresponding table to be selected within the database so the user just has to hit "Submit" and it posts the data into the corresponding table based on the option they choose in the drop down list. How would you achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried adding multiple select statements and setting an onchange event for when the option is selected but that did not work and I'm not sure how else to approach it

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: not sure how relevant it's a general question. I just want to know the general approach for this. Not my exact example solved. I should figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply name the options with the tables names:

```
<select name="options">
    <option value="table_a">optionA</option>
    <option value="table_b">optionB</option>
    <option value="table_c">optionC</option>
    <option value="table_d">optionD</option>
</select>
```

Then when submitting:

```
<?php
$tables = ["table_a", "table_b", "table_c", "table_d"];
$table = isset($_POST["table"]) && in_array($_POST["table"], $tables)
            ? $_POST["table"]
            : $tables[0];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$table`...";
```

Notice that you should make sure to check the table's name input. (like I checked if it's in the array)

If you want to be less repetitive, you can do:

```
$tables = [
    "table_a" => "optionA",
    "table_b" => "optionB",
    "table_c" => "optionC",
    "table_d" => "optionD",
];

// When building the form:
foreach ($tables as $tableName => $optionName) {
    echo "<option value='$tableName'>$optionName</option>";
}


// When submiting
$table = isset($_POST["table"], $tables[$_POST["table"]])
            ? $tables[$_POST["table"]]
            : $tables[0];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$table`...";
```